# active .bashrc setting in bash files

Tags: bash

Instead of using default python, in .bashrc I change "python" point to my own python version. However, when I write a bash scripts and call for python in it, it still uses the default python. Why is that, and how can I set it so that I do not have to add "source ~/.bashrc" to every sh file? Thanks

```
[yl@chh test]$ more test.sh 
echo `which python`
[yl@chh test]$ sh test.sh 
/usr/bin/python
[yl0@chh test]$ which python
alias python='~/tools/Python-2.7.3/python'
~/tools/Python-2.7.3/python
```

Comment: have you restarted the shell that's calling test.sh?

Comment: Do you want to do it programmatically? Have you thought about changing the link reference in the /usr/bin?

Answer (score 2):

From the `bash` man page:

> Aliases  are  not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless
>   the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the
>   description of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

It would probably be better to change your PATH rather than using an alias for this purpose.

Comment: it makes sense. But if adding "~/tools/Python-2.7.3" to PATH, "/usr/bin" is in priority, so default python will still be used.

Comment: Not if you put it ahead of /usr/bin/. What I generally do is put ~/bin at the beginning of my path, and put symlinks in ~/bin.